# Python 3 format method - tuple index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a problem with the format method in Python 3.4.2. Shows me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 2, line 3
builtins.IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The code:

```
A = "{0}={1}"
B = ("str", "string")
C = A.format(B)
print (C)
```

The tuple contains two strings with indexes 0 and 1 and this error should not be displayed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) you should be passing in the arguments as positional arguments, not as a tuple.  If you want to use the values in a tuple, use the `*` operator.

> ```
> str.format(*args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Perform a string formatting operation. The string on which this method is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces {}. Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument. Returns a copy of the string where each replacement field is replaced with the string value of the corresponding argument.
>
> "The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2)
>   'The sum of 1 + 2 is 3'

More specifically, you'd want to do the following:

```
A = "{0}={1}"
B = ("str", "string")
C = A.format(*B)
print (C)
```

or

```
A = "{0}={1}"
C = A.format("str", "string")
print (C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to unpack the tuple to have two arguments instead of one tuple:

```
A = "{0}={1}"
B = ("str", "string")
C = A.format(*B)
print (C)
```

Or modify your format string to accept one argument with two elements in a sequence.

```
A = "{0[0]}={0[1]}"
B = ("str", "string")
C = A.format(B)
print (C)
```