# What to do with this error on jacobi iteration with python

Tags: python, math, physics

i have a problem with my code, the console says

i | x1      | x2      | x3      | e1      | e2      | e3
0 |       0 |       0 |       0 | -       | -       | -
Traceback (most recent call last):

print(tabel.format(i, cx1, cx2, cx3), "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx1,bx1)),"{0:.2f}".format(error(cx2,bx2)), "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx3,bx3)))

IndexError: Replacement index 4 out of range for positional args tuple,

```
def x1(x2,x3):
    return (7.85 + (0.1*x2) + (0.2*3))/3

def x2 (x1,x3):
    return (-19.3 - (0.1 *x1) + (0.3 *x3))/7

def x3(x1,x2):
    return ((-0.3 * x1) + (0.2 *x2) +71.4)/10

def error(n,o):
    return ((n-o)/n) *100 

bx1, bx2, bx3 = 0, 0, 0

tabel = "{0:1} | {1:7} | {2:7} | {3:7} | {4:7} | {5:7} | {6:7}"

print(tabel.format("i", "x1", "x2", "x3", "e1", "e2", "e3"))
for i in range (0,5) :
    if i ==0 :
        print(tabel.format(i, bx1, bx2, bx3, "-", "-", "-"))
        cx1 = bx1 
        cx2 = bx2
        cx3 = bx3
        
    else:
        cx1 = eval("{0:.3f}".format(x1(bx2, bx3)))
        cx2 = eval("{0:.3f}".format(x2(bx1, bx3)))
        cx3 = eval("{0:.3f}".format(x3(bx1, bx2)))
        print(tabel.format(i, cx1, cx2, cx3), "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx1,bx1)),"{0:.2f}".format(error(cx2,bx2)), "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx3,bx3)))
```

how do i put the iteration inside the table and prevent the error

Comment: What is your `print` statement trying to do?

Comment: im trying to put the iteration inside the tabel, i ve edited the post, sorry for the trouble

Comment: I suggest breaking your long `print(tabel.format(i, cx1, cx2, cx3), "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx1,bx1)),"{0:.2f}".format(error(cx2,bx2)), "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx3,bx3)))` line into several smaller lines, so the error message can tell you more precisely where the error is.

Comment: You have an extra `)` in your `print`. Change it to `print(tabel.format(i, cx1, cx2, cx3, "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx1,bx1)), "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx2,bx2)), "{0:.2f}".format(error(cx3,bx3))))`

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286421/python-3-format-method-tuple-index-out-of-range

Comment: @Stef thanks man it seems the problem is within the )